# SQL Server Case expression conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I am currently working on a data flow and have been given a specific requirement that i am trying to complete.

In my table I have a column which is partially `NULL` due to a couple of reasons.

What I'm trying to do is write a `case` expression within my select statement that has two conditions:

When `NULL` use a different value from another column (which is pulled from another table using a join)

If the column is still `NULL` (in both cases) then use a different value from another column in the table which will ensure the column is populated.

So basically, if it's `NULL` do this, if its still `NULL`, then do this which will mean my column is populated as i intend.

I've been playing around but have been unable to produce the required result. Is this something that can be achieved using a `CASE` expression ?

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: There are no `Case` (`Switch`) statements in T-SQL, only `CASE` **expressions**. You won't be able to use a `Switch` as the language does not support them.

Answer (score 3):

You are describing the [`coalesce()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function:

```
coalesce(col1, col2, col3)
```

You can use this in either a `select` or `update`.